# Can the finalize() method be called twice if the garbage collector retains memory twice in the same code?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I found it in many places that the finalize() method in java is called when the garbage  collector or System.gc() has successfully retained the memory consumed by the redundant object with no more references to it. Also found that this method is called not more than a single time. I am not new to java but also not pretty much experienced. I may have a wrong understanding of it but let's say a piece of code

```
public class Solution {
    @Override
    protected void finalize(){
        System.out.print("method called");
    }
    public static void main(String... args){
        Solution obj1= new Solution();
        Solution obj2 = new Solution();
        Solution obj3 = new Solution();
        System.gc();
        obj1=obj2;
        System.gc();
        obj3=null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Here, the finalize method is called twice because the memory heap becomes eligible for garbage cleaning two times. So, I am a bit confused whether I know the whole thing right or if it is supposed to behave the way it's behaving.

Comment: It's getting called twice because two seperate instances are being GCd

Comment: Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: `finalize()` is called for every Object that is collected.

Comment: Okay so it's not like it's gonna be called once irrespective of the number of objects collected? It will be called again and again whenever a distinct object is collected as a garbage from the memory heap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The `finalize()` method will only be called once by the GC on an object.  The JVM sets a flag in the object header (I think) to say that it has been finalized, and won't finalize it again.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) states this explicitly:

> *" The finalize method is never invoked more than once by a Java virtual machine for any given object. "*

Of course, there is nothing to stop an object method from calling `this.finalize()` any number of times.

---

Note that `finalize()` is **deprecated** in Java 9 and later for reasons stated in the javadoc.  It is recommended that you switch to using one of the following instead:

- `AutoCloseable` + try with resources
- `Cleaner`
- `PhantomReference`

---

Someone commented thus:

> `finalize()` is called for *every* `Object` that is collected.

This is not true for a couple of reasons.

- The javadoc *explicitly* states that there are no guarantees that `finalize` will ever be called.  The thing that is guaranteed is that it will be called (once) before an object's storage is reclaimed.  That is a weaker statement than the statement that the comment makes.

  One scenario where garbage collected objects may not be finalized is if the JVM exits soon after a GC run.

  Another (pathological) scenario occurs when a classes `finalize` method never returns<sup>1</sup>.  When an instance of that class is finalized, the finalizer thread will get stuck.  When all finalizer threads are stuck in that way, no more finalizable objects can be finalized<sup>2</sup>.
- If the `Object::finalize` is not overridden in a class, the JVM will skip the finalization step for that class.

---

<sup>1 - This could be due to an infinite loop, or because the `finalize()` method gets stuck waiting on a lock or waiting for an internal or external "event" that never happens.  Note also that "never" could mean "not for a long time" in this context.  The overall impact can be the same.

2 - The objects will sit in the finalization queue indefinitely.  This is a memory leak.</sup>

Comment: Another scenario: create a few objects whose `finalize()` method contains an infinite loop and let them get collected. Once all finalizer threads are busy, no other collected object's finalize() method will ever get called.